# Using react useRef() --why my ref is null?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple example

```
function Node() {
    const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true);
    const inputRef = useRef(null)
    console.log(inputRef);
    return (
        <div>
            {!hidden && <h2 ref={inputRef}>Hello World</h2>}
            {hidden && <button onClick={() => setHidden(false)}>Show Child</button>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Upon clicking the button, I would expect that the h2 DOM element is attached to my ref. However, I found that the ref.current is still null upon logging, but if I expand the object, it contains the DOM node.

How am I supposed to access the DOM element via my ref? At the time I want to reference it, for example **inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()**, it's always shown as null.
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your log is just to early, at the time it runs the ref hasn't been assigned yet, it'll be there in `useEffect`, you should put your logic there

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the ref in the render phase, but the ref will be populate once React paint the screen, in the commit phase.
So, call it in a `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect`

```
// run synchronously after all DOM mutations
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  // do something with inputRef
}, [])
```

Comment: What if I want to display the coordinates of my ref in my render? Will I need to somehow force another render? For example, I want to have ```<div>{inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width}</div>```

Comment: yeah, you need to set state in the use effect with the value from `inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width`

Answer (score 0):

Your ref is not initialize when setHidden set to false if you want to use it you need some interactions like this

```
        import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    function App() {
        const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true);
        const inputRef = useRef(null)
        console.log(inputRef);
        const handleChange=()=>{
        console.log(inputRef);
          
        }

useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(inputRef);
},[hidden])
        return (
            <div>
              <input onChange ={handleChange}></input>
                {!hidden && <h2 ref={inputRef}>Hello World</h2>}
                {hidden && <button onClick={() => setHidden(false)}>Show Child</button>}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: you are calling consle.log(inputRef) too early before code reachs {!hidden && <h2 ref={inputRef}>Hello World</h2>}

Comment: What if I want to display the coordinates of my ref in my render? Will I need to somehow force another render? For example, I want to have <div>{inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width}</div>

Comment: Maks your operation inside useEffect(()=>{},[hidden])